# Strict conditional symbol without changing the default font?

Tags: symbols, logic, relation-symbols

Here is how to define `\strictif` as the strict conditional ⥽ from modal logic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\strictif}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{74}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
$$p \strictif q$$

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

I'm not happy with this solution, however, because loading package `pxfonts` changes the default fonts of my document.  Is there a way to define `\strictif` so that I can access only the ⥽ symbol from that font without changing the default fonts of my document?

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `$$...$$`. Use `\[...\]` instead

Comment: Have you tried removing `\usepackage{pxfonts}`?

Comment: You're importing the symbol already with `\Declare....` macros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you don't actually need the `\usepackage{pxfonts}` line; if you remove it, your font goes back to Computer Modern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbolsC}{U}{txsyc}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\strictif}{\mathrel}{symbolsC}{74}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\[p \strictif q\]

\end{document}
```

[image]